# .net core middleware and authorization

Tags: c#, .net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-middleware

I have a custom middleware that is configured like this

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseWhen(context => GetCondition(context)
                , appBuilder =>
       {
            appBuilder.UseAuthentication(); // this does not do the trick
            appBuilder.UseAuthorization();// this does not do the trick
            appBuilder.UseMiddleware<MyCustomMiddleware>();
       });
}
```

I want my custom middleware to execute only when the user is authorized to do so.

If I am using controller, I can provide Authorize attribute on controller which forces the user to login or 401 if they are not logged-in.

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
```

How can I do the similar authorization in middleware. One way to do is to check in the invoke method if user is authenticated but that does not seems right to me

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        // my code goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: You would check the Invoke method and httpcontext.  Why does that not seem right to you?

Comment: It is because the middleware should not be "executed" if the user is not authenticated. If I check within middleware then middleware is executed. Additionally, I want my middleware to be unaware of authentication/authorization status of request.

Comment: Just because you check something you don't have to execute it you can execute your logic based on a condition otherwise the middleware will just continue and be ignored.

Comment: Hi @Tahir, what do you mean `but that does not seems right to me`? Any error message or it always false? It should works well to judge the user if it is authenticated.

Comment: @Rena, no error message but I feel the middleware should not aware of authentication/authorization status of request. (segregation of duties).

Comment: UseWhen is the right approach but doing the equivalent of the authorize attribute is alot more code.